# How to unfold a Matrix on Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a given matrix `H` and I would like to **unfold** (expand) it to find a matrix `B` by following the method below :

Let `H` be a matrix of dimension `m × n`. Let `x = gcd (m,n)`

1. The matrix `H` is cut in two parts.
2. The cutting pattern being such that :

- The "diagonal cut" is made by alternately moving `c = n/x` units to the right (we move `c` units to the right several times).
- We alternately move `c-b = m/x` units down (i.e. `b = (n-m)/x`) (we move `b` units down several times).

3. After applying this "diagonal cut" of the matrix, we copy and paste the two parts repeatedly to obtain the matrix B.

**Exemple** : Let the matrix `H` of dimension `m × n = 5 × 10` defined by :

```
 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0  
 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1  
 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0  
 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1  
 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1
```

- Let's calculate `x = gcd (m,n) = gcd (5,10) = 5`,
- Alternatively move to the right : `c = n/x = 10/5 = 2`,
- Alternatively move down : `b = (n-m)/x = (10-5)/5 = 1`.

1. Diagonal cutting diagram : The matrix `H` is cut in two parts.
   The cutting pattern is such that :

- We move `c = 2` units to the right several times `c = 2` units to the right,
- We repeatedly move `c - b = 1` unit downwards.

We get : [image]

[image]

[image]

2. After applying this "diagonal cut" of the matrix, we copy and paste the two parts repeatedly to obtain the matrix :

[image]

Remark : In the matrices `X`, `X1` and `X2` the dashes are zeros.

3. The resulting matrix `B` is (`L` is factor) :

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by creating a logical mask with the cutting pattern, and then element-wise multiplying the input by the mask and by its negation. Repeating by `L` can be done with `blkdiag`.

```
H = [1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
     0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
     1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0
     0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1
     1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1];
L = 2;
[m, n] = size(H);
x = gcd(m, n);
c = n / x;
b = (n-m)/x;
mask = repelem(tril(true(m/b)), b, c);
A = [H.*mask; H.*~mask];
A = repmat({A}, L, 1);
B = blkdiag(A{:});
```